# Django merge queries to speed up database access

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle, oracle11g

I create a list of queries with a loop:

```
chunks = 1000
chunkTimeInS = (endDate - startDate).total_seconds()/chunks

queryList=[]

for timeChunk in range(0,chunks):
    startTime=startDate+timedelta(seconds=chunkTimeInS*timeChunk)
    endTime=startDate+timedelta(seconds=chunkTimeInS*(timeChunk+1))

    queryList.append(myModel.objects.using('myDB')
        .exclude(myValue1=-99)
        .filter(timestamp__gte=startTime, timestamp__lt=endTime)
        .order_by("timestamp")
        .aggregate(
            Avg('myValue1'),
            Avg('myValue2'),
            myValue3 = Avg(F('myValue3')*F('myValue3')),
            )
        )
```

I want to save all data to a list by doing: `dataList=list(queryList)`. This call takes way too long. I guess is due to the large amount of queries in the queryList.

Is there a way to merge this list into one query? Or maybe other solutions to speed up the database access.

The database which is used is Oracle 11g.

Comment: If you have querysets in the list then `data = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, queryList)` would work. However you have `aggregate` statement, then it's a list of dictionaries not a list of querysets. I deleted my answer.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to avoid the loop to speed up the DB access?